# Setup and running examples in Oryx2

Tags: apache-kafka, cloudera, oryx

I have a CDH5.5 installation and I want to run some oryx2 examples within my virtual machine.

I've already downloaded and compiled oryx2 from github successfully. I've copied the example app to my ORYX_HOME/deploy/bin folder where oryx-run.sh is placed. I've also added the wordcount-example.conf and add a oryx.conf file from the als one (I pointed to my kafka-brokers and zk-servers within it).

I tried to setup Kafka and/or run some examples but I always get the same error:

```
 > ./oryx-run.sh kafka-setup  --layer-jar ../oryx-batch/target/oryx-batch-2.2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
Can't find kafka scripts like kafka-topics 


> ./oryx-run.sh batch --conf wordcount-example.conf --app-jar myapp.jar --layer-jar ../oryx-batch/target/oryx-batch-2.2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
Can't find kafka scripts like kafka-topics
```

I've tried copying kafka script to the same oryx-run script folder but got the same errors unfortunately.

Any idea?

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

```
export KAFKA_HOME=/opt/17173/kafka
export PATH=$HADOOP_HOME/bin:$SPARK_HOME/sbin:$KAFKA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is kafka-topics can't be found in bin, you have to add it to PATH. For me, Kafka is in /Users/long/software/kafka_2.10-0.8.2.2, so I just 
`vim ~/.bashrc` ,then add follow two lines in the end.

`export KAFKA_HOME=/Users/long/software/kafka_2.10-0.8.2.2
export PATH=$KAFKA_HOME/bin:$PATH;`

After add it, You must restart Shell.